# NameError: name 'Query' is not defined

Tags: python

```
@app.get("/get-by-name")
def get_item(name: str = Query(None, tittle="Name", description="name of item.")):
    for item_id in inventory:
        if inventory[item_id]["name"] == name:
            return inventory[item_id]
    return {"Data": "Not Found"}
```

Hola estimada comunidad, estoy aprendiendo FastApi y tengo el siguiente error en mi funcion get, muchas gracias de antemano por su gentil ayuda.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\fpdf.py", line 51, in 
def get_item(name: str = Query(None, tittle="Name", description="name of item.")):
NameError: name 'Query' is not defined

Comment: procura que importaste `Query` de `fastapi`:

`from fastapi import FastAPI, Query`

Comment: Gracias =) sigo aprendiendo aún pero me entusiasma mucho!